# Create Mysql datetime column with default 0000-00-00

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want to create a table with column like this.

```
CREATE  TABLE `user_gender` (
  `user_gender_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_gender_title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `user_gender_modified_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ,
  `user_gender_created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_gender_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

but it seem that the default 0000-00-00 cant work in mysql. however i imitated it from joomla database model so I am pretty sure that it should work correctly. but my phpadmin keep saying there is a syntax errors in -00-00. can anyone explain this?

Comment: If you'll pardon me questioning the premise of this question: a better default for "no date has been set" is `NULL`, whose purpose is to represent an unknown value, rather than a nonsense date value. Further, a Modified date *can* conceivably be NULL immediately after the record is created, while a Created date *must* have a valid value. I would define the columns with appropriate null-ability and avoid specifying defaults.

Comment: @DanJ - Agreed, this stems from a conceptualizing problem.  loval/hival values are clearly being used as a stand-in for proper null handling and application design.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, since i use joomla before I started coding. So I think joomla database is a good model to follow. that why  I created the model with default date just like Joomla did. I will consider your method. Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the drefault values in quotes:

```
CREATE  TABLE `user_gender` (
  `user_gender_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_gender_title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `user_gender_modified_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,
  `user_gender_created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_gender_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Explanation: MySQL does not have a date literal format so you use strings.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I generated it from MySQL workbench so i have no idea that it was the wrong way. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes on the default values.

```
CREATE  TABLE `user_gender` (
`user_gender_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`user_gender_title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
`user_gender_modified_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,
`user_gender_created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_gender_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I generated it from MySQL workbench. so It seems that workbench is not a good tool

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been broken with MySQL 5.5.  I recently upgraded and broke an application which relied on a value of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' being set in a specific instance.  It always worked previously, but no longer does with the only change being a platform version update.